# Change the Target App Size when using LaunchUriAsync in Windows Universal Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, win-universal-app, windows, windows-10-universal

I just started playing around with Windows App Development. I am trying to open a browser window from the app on a button click. I want the `Target App` (in this case my `window browser`) to be of a smaller size. Better if I can give the size by some means.

I found that `DesiredRemainingView` will do the trick but it somehow does not.

Any help is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ViewSizePreference UseHalf { get; private set; }

        //public ViewSizePreference UseHalf { get; private set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            greetingOutput.Text = "Hello, " + nameInput.Text + "!";
        }

        async private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //greetingOutput.Text = UseHalf.ToString();
            // The URI to launch
            var uriBing = new Uri("http://www.bing.com");

            // Set the option to show a warning
            var promptOptions = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            //promptOptions.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
            promptOptions.DesiredRemainingView = UseHalf;

            // Launch the URI
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriBing, promptOptions);

            if (success)
            {
                // URI launched
            }
            else
            {
                // URI launch failed
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can use the [LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView](http://www.bing.com) to specify the target app’s desired view size. But what kinds of the Windows Browser are you using?

If your Windows Browser is the **Internet Explorer or Edge**, please make sure that you have closed the Windows Browser before you run the source app, after that it will open a new Windows Browser to show the target app which goes to the [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com) website and the LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView will work fine.

But if we do not close the Windows Browser(**Internet Explorer or Edge**), after that when we run the source app, the target app will append as a new tab of the current Windows Browser instead of opening a new Windows Browser. In this way we can not see the effect which the LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView should bring.

But if your Windows Brower is the **Chrome** or other third part browsers, the [LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView](http://www.bing.com) may not wokr. The reason for the third part browsers can not reply on [LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView](http://www.bing.com) to implement the correct behavior may be related with the internal settings of the browsers. Because if we want to implement the launching function correctly, the target app needs to understand the Protocols or Rule or others theory.

The following is the result after closing the Windows Brower Edge before running the App:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Feng. Thank you for the detailed explanation on how the method works. Could you please tell me more on what other way I can make the browser window open in a smaller size than my app so that it'd look more like a mini browser. This can be attained in JavaScript when dealing with web pages and HTML. But how do you do that from a Windows Universal app? For the sake of simplicity let's assume that the browser is Edge.